# SharePoint 2010 "save conflict" message when editing list item with attachment

Tags: save, conflict

I have been trying to address an error generated in SharePoint 2010 that occurs when I update a list item that has a Microsoft Office document attached.  If I make changes to the attached document (by clicking its link in the list item) and then attempt to save the list item I get the error message below.

[save_conflict_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxgWa.jpg)

I am trying to capture and deal with this error using the *ItemUpdating* event receiver

The receiver **never** catches the save conflict exception in the try catch.

I have tried everything that has been suggested in about 4 pages of google searches and I have run out of things to try.  This is a last desperate attempt to find a solution (if there IS one).

Below is my code for the **ItemUpdating** event receiver.

```
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

        try
        {

            base.ItemUpdating(properties);                

            using (SPSite site = properties.OpenSite())
            {

                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                    //determine list
                    if (properties.List.Title.ToLower() == "mytestlist")
                    {

                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                        properties.List.Update();

                    }   //endif


                }    //end using

            }    //end using

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            {

                //abort the update
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                properties.Cancel = true;

            }   //end try
        }

    }    //end function
```

Here is my *Elements.xml* file also.

[elements_xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyDNA.jpg)

Thank you in advance.
:)